# Strange pagination behavior giving white page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I' am using WordPress pagination. I have used this code on my other pages and it's working fine in there, but on this page "schedules" when I try to goto next paged link it gives white page.

I have reset Permalink Settings because thats the only solution i found on the Internet. Still nothing same problem.

In the database their are total of 9 records under this custom post type so by pagination it will be 3 per page.

**Pagination Code**

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'schedules', 
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged
);
query_posts($args);
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $schedules_vessel = get_field('schedules_vessel');
        $schedules_voyage = get_field('schedules_voyage');
        $schedules_port = get_field('schedules_port');
        $schedules_country = get_field('schedules_country');
        $schedules_arrival = get_field('schedules_arrival');
        $schedules_departure = get_field('schedules_departure');
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', $schedules_arrival);
        $schedules_arrival_date = $date->format('d M Y');
        $schedules_arrival_time = $date->format('G:i');
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', $schedules_departure);
        $schedules_departure_date = $date->format('d M Y');
        $schedules_departure_time = $date->format('G:i');
?>          
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php require_once( get_template_directory() . "/snippets/pagination.php"); ?>
```

**In pagination.php**

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $temp = "";
    $big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text' => 'Previous',
        'next_text' => 'Next',
        'type' => 'list'
    ));
?>
<?php 
$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate answering my own question but yes I found the solution. The problem was with the custom post type slug "schedules" was had the same slug as the page name "schedules" I think that was conflicting, well I don't think it should but anyways.